# Add an array as post content dynamically

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am working on a code where I need to insert the array as the content in wordpress admin .

I am using below code

```
$newArray = array();
$new_post = array(
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'post_title'=>"New post created Programmatically",
        'post_content'=>"$newArray"
        );
        wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

So Please guide me How can I use array as post_content in creating custom posts.

Comment: You have to remove double quotes like this : `'post_content'=>$newArray` $newArray not need to passed in quotes. I that defined array you can pass fields etc

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of data your array contains.  But you would need to first loop your array; and create a valid string for passing into the `post_content` argument.

For example, if your array consisted of text strings:

```
$newArray = array( 'test_1', 'test_2', 'test_3' );
$text = '';

// Loop the array and create a text string
foreach( $newArray as $string ) {

    $text .= $string . ' | ';
}
```

Now you can insert the text into the post content.

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'post_title'=>"New post created Programmatically",
    'post_content'=> $text
);
wp_insert_post($new_post);
```